# Symfony3 doctrine Many-to-Many column not found on select

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.2

I'm begginer with Symfony and Doctrine and I have a problem with a many-to-many relationship.
I have the next two entities, relationated with many-to-many.

AppBundle/Entity/User.php

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Team", mappedBy="user", cascade={"all"})
*
*/
private $team;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->team = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add team
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Team $team
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function addTeam(\AppBundle\Entity\Team $team)
{
    $this->team[] = $team;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove team
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Team $team
 */
public function removeTeam(\AppBundle\Entity\Team $team)
{
    $this->team->removeElement($team);
}

/**
 * Get team
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getTeam()
{
    return $this->team;
}
```

AppBundle/Entity/Team.php

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="team", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_team")
*/
private $user;

public function __construct()
{

    $this->user = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add user
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $user
 *
 * @return Team
 */
public function addUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $user)
{
    $this->user[] = $user;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove user
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $user
 */
public function removeUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $user)
{
    $this->user->removeElement($user);
}

/**
 * Get user
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}
```

In my controller, I have the following code:

AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();        
$em->getRepository('AppBundle:Team')->findBy(array('user'=>$usr));
```

And I have te next error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name
>   AS name_2, t0.description AS description_3, t0.active AS active_4,
>   t0.date_add AS date_add_5, t0.date_modified AS date_modified_6 FROM
>   team t0 WHERE user_team.user_id = ?' with params [2]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'user_team.user_id' in 'where clause' 500 Internal Server Error -
>   InvalidFieldNameException

What are i'm doing wrong?

The relation?
The controller?
Maybe everything?

Thank you :)

Comment: Somehow Doctrine is missing the whole `JOIN` - try clearing your cache (`php bin/console cache:clear`) and look if doctrine wants to update your schema somehow: `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`.

Comment: How is the table user_team looks like?

Comment: Thank you guys :)

Comment: I tried to clear cache and update schema, but the problem still exists.

@kormik the user_teams table seems ok:
team_id -> int (11) -> foreign key: referenced table: team; referenced fields: id
user_id -> int (11) -> foreign key: references table: fos_user; referenced fields: id

Thank you

Comment: I think symfony may be confused by your terms. Try changing your ArrayCollection variables to have plural names, like `$users` rather than `$user`, and `$teams` rather than `$team`. Change relevant functions to match. Next, clarify for us what you are trying to achieve. Are you looking for a list of users on a team, or a list of teams for a given user? Either way, you can just use the functions in your entities to get at these. No need to use `findBy` to get these.

Comment: Doctrine doesn't care about names of your properties. You can use $user or  $users or whatever. But to keep your code readable and understandable, you should rename them and use plurals as @ehymel suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm It seems that you forgot to run `doctrine:schema:update` command here.

Also, try fix this annotation:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="team", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_team")
*/
```

to something like

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User")
 * @JoinTable(name="User_Team",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="team_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get users of a Team,
use your getUser function on a Team object:

```
$em    = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$team  = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Team')->find( $aTeamId );

$users = $team->getUser();
```